# Accessing phpMyAdmin in Laravel Homestead with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

After a night of frustration with the steep learning curve in setting up Laravel Homestead and getting it to work without any problems, I come across this one problem that I cannot seem to find a solution to. How do I manage my databases in a Laravel Homestead instance, using phpmyadmin?

Ideally, I would like to access it from my pre-configured phpMyAdmin in XAMPP, located in `C:/xampp/`. But I did not set up my Laravel project in `C:/xampp/htdocs/`, which seems to be where XAMPP gets its databases from. I created the Laravel project in `~\Google Drive\College\...\Project\`, so it has no connection to my XAMPP installation. How can I manage/create databases for my Laravel project using XAMPP?

I've tried installing phpmyadmin in Laravel Homestead directly, but it just creates it as another 'project', right next to the one I am trying to use it for, as in `~\Google Drive\College\...\phpMyAdmin\`. (If this is how it is supposed to be, then how do I use that phpMyAdmin installation/instance to access and modify my project's databases?)

Going to `localhost:8000/home` properly delivers my index page within my project's public directory, but there is no phpMyAdmin accessible by going to `localhost:8000/home/phpMyAdmin` or `localhost:8000/phpMyAdmin`. However, with my Apache and mySQL servers on in XAMPP, I can access my local (yet external from the project) phpMyAdmin installation with its databases.

What aspect of this am I missing, to not be able to work with databases? I'd appreciate any help. I've been up all night trying to figure this out.

Comment: you can hijack xampp's phpmyadmin configuration, go to `xampp\phpmyadmin` look for `config.inc.php`. change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';` to point to your homestead ip address. assuming your [homestead is ready](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead). or you could simply [install phpmyadmin to your homestead](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin), it's basically an ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hijacking XAMPP's phpMyAdmin config did not work. What the problem really was, was a proper mapping of the file directory, setting up the config files to match, and then re-provisioning to apply the config changes. XAMPP was never even needed. In detail, this is the configuration that worked:

**In Homestead.yaml:**

> ```
> folders: 
> # The iMeetUp project folder is contained within the project folder specified here:
> - map: C:/Users/****/******/******/Project Files/ 
>   to: /home/vagrant/Code
> # The above directory is where the local project folder should be mapped to within your Homestead VM. So the mapping works as follows: Map from local, to VM.
>
> sites:
> - map: imeetups.local
>   to: /home/vagrant/Code/iMeetUp/public
> # This mapping, when combined with the hosts file edit, enables you to access your app at http://imeetups.local:8000
>
> databases:
> - iMeetUp
> ```

Add this to your `hosts` file located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` (make sure to open the file with your code editor of choice (mine is [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)) and that you launched that editor with `Run As Administrator` enabled):

`127.0.0.1      imeetups.local`

In your Laravel project, change the following part of this file to match:
**iMeetUp/app/config/local/database.php:**

> ```
>   'mysql' => array(
>         'driver'    => 'mysql',
>         'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
>         'database'  => 'iMeetUp',
>         'username'  => 'homestead',
>         'password'  => 'secret',
>         'charset'   => 'utf8',
>         'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
>         'prefix'    => '',
>     ),
> ```
>
> The username and password for homestead's database is what is used, the same one described on their [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#daily-usage).

Lastly, you must re-initialize the project - no need to `vagrant destroy` the entire thing. Just run this within your Homestead folder in command prompt, wherever you saved your Homestead installation:

```
Git bash init.sh
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you have Git bash installed and included in your PATH file. Then you can just run `init.sh` from the Homestead folder, and it should automatically launch a Git bash window. 
In the dialog, choose `yes` to overwrite all 3 configuration files it will ask about. I first made the mistaken assumption the first file was asking about overwriting the `homestead.yaml` file, but then I noticed it is referring to the cached version of the file, so you definitely should say yes to it and not no.

After initialization, you need to re-provision the entire project. Run in your Homestead directory:

> vagrant up --provision

Or, if your VM is currently running,

> vagrant reload --provision

This will force the project to re-apply its cache setup of config files.
Now your app should work and be connected to the database, and the site should be accessible at any of the following addresses:

```
http://localhost:8000
http://127.0.0.1:8000
http://imeetup.local:8000
```

Also, if you plan to use Laravel's built in Auth:: framework, you'll need to change the framework to use the databases instead. For example:

**iMeetUp/app/config/auth.php:**

> ```
> 'driver' => 'database', 
> 'model' => 'member', 
> 'table' => 'members',
> ```
>
> The table should match your default/primary user/member table in your database, and the model should be referencing the name of the user/member model file you are using in `iMeetUps/app/models`.

With this setup, your app should appropriately use your Homestead's database. I was not able to find any extensive, clear, detailed solutions to this problem, so I decided to write one up myself. I hope this helps someone else save a weekends-worth of time, which is how long it took me to figure this out.